# Kendo Datepicker error: sets previous day with manual input (Angular)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have an issue with Kendo Datepicker which only happens when the date is written **manually** in the input (when selected from the widget it works perfectly fine).

> The problem is that it sets the previous day of the day inserted in
> the input.

To avoid this the widget apparently sets the hours with value different of 00:00:00 automatically.
But when changing the input manually - the hours are automatically set to 00:00:00 and when send to the server through the http call Angular parses the date of **Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:00** to the previous day, which I guess makes sense, since it would have to be at least **Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:01** in order to keep the date 02.
These are the dates I have just before the server call:

> manualDate: Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 // -> converts to 01.02.2020
>
> widgetDate: Thu Feb 02 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100

And here is my html:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="startDate"
        filter="date"
        editor="date"
        format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
        width="20">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate
            let-dataItem>
            {{ dataItem.startDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template KendoGridEditTemplate
            let-dataItem="dataItem"
            let-column="column">
            <kendo-datepicker [value]="dataItem.startDate"
                [format]="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
                [formControl]="formGroup?.get('startDate')">
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1648

Comment: Yes, it´s a matter of time-zones. I guess the setup would depend on the business logic if the firm is international.